# Change color of notification in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I am trying to use the funcion "showNotification" to display a green pop up.
The official documentation says, you can use the parameter 'type' to change the color.

```
type    A string which controls the color of the notification. One of "default" (gray), "message" (blue), "warning" (yellow), or "error" (red).
```

Has anyone tried this before?
Is there any way to use the HTML/HEX codes?

UPDATE
I ended up re-coloring the single types of showNotifications like this:

```
 tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                                                 .shiny-notification-error {
                                                  background-color:#FF5757;
                                                  color:#000000;
                                                 }
                                                  .shiny-notification-message {
                                                  background-color:#B5E26F;
                                                  color:#000000;
                                                 }
                                                 '))),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add some style yourself:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML(".shiny-notification {background-color:#112446;}")
      )
    ),
    actionButton("show", "Show")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showNotification("Message text",action = a(href = "javascript:location.reload();", "Reload page"),type = "warning"
      )
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: So this makes all my popups the same colour, right? Is it possible to add an id to a color? so lets say your code gets the id 'dark' and if i use 'type=dark' the popup gets dark, 'type=error' still is red?

Comment: Have a look at the `shinyBS` package, which has `style` feature https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Alerts.html